# Как изменить размер tableviewcell при клике на кнопку?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

У меня есть таблица, в которой отображаются записи (грубо говоря картинка, название и кнопка), мне надо сделать так, что бы при клике на эту самую кнопку мой TableViewCell (в котором и находится кнопка) увеличивала свою высоту.

К примеру она была высотой 70 пикселей и там отображались только эти три элемента, но при клике на кнопку её высота становится равна 290 пикселей и там отображается что-нибудь ещё (как сделать это - знаю).

Пробовал повесить в свой класс для TableViewCell функцию обработки кнопки:

```
self.frame.size.height = 280;
self.bounds.size.height = 280;
self.contentView.frame.size.height = 280;
scrollView.frame.size.height = 280;
```

И она даже увеличивается и показывает мой scrollView, только проблема в том, что она не расширяется (то есть остальные cell спускаются вниз), а просто отображает эту информацию на них, перекрывая...

Помогите пожалуйста, а то в гугле и яндексе так и не смог найти нужной информации(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На swift не знаю как будет, но знаю как будет на obj-c, смысл один и тот же, немного синтаксис будет другой, так вот:

1. Во первых вы должны делать обработчик не в самой ячейке, а использовать уже написанный метод делегата: `tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath`.
2. Второе - в этом методе, Вы должны будете обновить таблицу, предварительно записав, под каким номером, была выбрана ячейка:

   ```
   self.selectedIndex = indexPathRow;
   [self.tableView beginUpdates]; 
   [self.tableView endUpdates];
   ```
3. В методе, который отвечает за высоту вашей ячейки, будем смотреть, если это обычная ячейка, то она будет обыкновенной высоты, если же, это ячейка, которую мы выделили, то она будет большего размера -

   ```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       if (indexPath.row == self.selectedIndex) {
           return  290;
       }
       else 
           return 70;
       }
   ```

Comment: Если будут вопросы, задавайте, помогу разобраться

Comment: Большое спасибо, хоть какая-то информация! Буду разбираться)

Comment: Будет что непонятно, обращайтесь))

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо Вам большущее, а то убил пол дня на это)

Comment: @DEM909 Рад был помочь, обращайтесь))