# Расширить ячейку для предоставления дополнительной информации

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

есть кастомная ячейка которая содержит кнопку, по нажатию на которую ячейка становится больше по высоте и появляется UILabel, в котором предоставлено небольшое сообщение.

Ячейки не состоят в секциях. По нажатию на остальную область ячейки происходит переход на detailView.

Вопрос: Как сделать чтобы ячейка при нажатии на кнопку увеличивалась в высоте и предоставляла информацию в этой же ячейке (не создавала новые)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458039/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-tableviewcell-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тоже самое что в [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458039/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-tableviewcell-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83)
только вам, нужно будет, вывести делегат нажатия на кнопку из ячейки и уже в этом делегате делать:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates]; 
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

А в самой ячейке вам нужно смотреть, какого она размера, если стандартного, то не рисовать UILabel или прятать его, если он есть, а если не стандартного размера, то рисовать UILabel, или показывать его, если он скрыт.

Comment: а если ячейка сделана в отдельном XIB файле со своим CustomTableCellVC, а таблица располагает TableVC классом в котором  и есть моя таблица, как связаться с этой таблицей и как отслеживать что кнопка была нажата именно в ячейке, на которую сделали тап, (ячейки грузятся динамически)

Comment: Во первых лучше классы называть CustomTableViewCell,  и не важно где сделана ваша ячейка, в сториборде или в ксибе, главное что бы у нее был свой класс. В этом классе вы пишете метод - IBAction метод, обработчик нажатия на кнопку, в этом методе вызываете делегат, который вы ранее должны объявить в этом классе. Вы подписываете ваш контроллер на этот делегат, и в нем делаете то, что я выше написал. И лучше сделать делегат, который будет возвращать ячейку, что бы вы потом могли узнать, какой у нее индекс методом [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; И запишите этот индекс в свойство.

Comment: Потом смотрите метод определения высоты ячейки, по прикрепленной ссылке в ответе, и делайте по аналогии

Comment: Делегат создавать нужно в классе с ячейкой? Либо в классе с Таблицей?

Comment: Создавать в ячейке, но подписывайся в классе с таблицей. Изучите хорошо делегаты, это важная тема.

Comment: изучил статью на хабре про делегаты, но все никак н емогу понять что стоит вызывать.
Я сделал пока что изменение размера ячейки по простому нажатию на ячейку.
Но вот что написать в обработчике кнопки я так и не понял
По хорошему мне нужно в этом обработчике вызвать метод `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` Но как ему передать индекс этой ячейки я так и не понял

Comment: @Northex вы ошибаетесь в том, где вам нужно вызвать этот метод, это раз, во вторых, вам действительно нужно разобраться с делегатами и делегированием, посмотрите примеры реализации, разберитесь самостоятельно с этим, это основа основ))